# AngularJS отлов входящих массивов

Tags: angularjs

Всем доброго дня. При переходе по ссылке: `/device/api/58sdfdc8d0a82sddb3be7sds2f9e79s`
Возвращается массив вида: `[{"md2":"f5dsfdfsds56s5s56ds","rid":1714811436,"type":0,"name":null,"date":"1502108910"},{"md2":"f5dsfdfsds56s5s56ds","rid":595975795,"type":0,"name":null,"date":"1502108910"},{"md2":"f5dsfdfsds56s5s56ds","rid":26726777,"type":0,"name":null,"date":"1502108910"}]`
Как средствами AngularJS, можно вывести значения md2, rid, type, name и date? Честно говоря, испытываю проблемы при обработке массива в контроллере, если он вообще необходим.
Спасибо всем за внимание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.controller('TestCntr', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.data = [];
  $http.get('/getdata/json') // URL условный, в этой песочнице, разумеется, будет ошибка...
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
  }).catch(function(response) { // сэмулируем ответ тут
    $scope.data = [{
      "md2": "f5dsfdfsds56s5s56ds",
      "rid": 1714811436,
      "type": 0,
      "name": null,
      "date": "1502108910"
    }, {
      "md2": "f5dsfdfsds56s5s56ds",
      "rid": 595975795,
      "type": 0,
      "name": null,
      "date": "1502108910"
    }, {
      "md2": "f5dsfdfsds56s5s56ds",
      "rid": 26726777,
      "type": 0,
      "name": null,
      "date": "1502108910"
    }];  
  });
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller='TestCntr'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>md2</td>
      <td>rid</td>
      <td>type</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat='row in data'>
      <td>{{row.md2}}</td>
      <td>{{row.rid}}</td>
      <td>{{row.type}}</td>
      <td>{{row.name ? row.name : '---'}}</td>
      <td>{{row.date}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Подскажите, для того чтобы контроллер получил эти массивы, надо как-то из него выполнять Ajax запрос и результат уже подсовывать в  $scope.data или это выполняется как-то ещё. Дело в том, что по параметру ссылки ('58sdfdc8d0a82sddb3be7sds2f9e79s'), из б.д. выбираются записи, в кот. есть вхождение, которые затем напросто отображаются на странице.

Comment: Добавляя массивы в ручную, я получаю необходимые записи. Не совсем понятно, как ответ из б.д. передать в контроллер.

Comment: В контроллере вызываете сервис получения данных, результат присваиваете в переменную.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы привести пример. Просто в голове начинает вариться такая каша.

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов Модифицировал немного код с примером использования запроса к серверу (сам запрос не работает, потому что в примере данные грузить неоткуда, но идея должна быть понятна)

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек. Всех благ тебе =)